# \captionsetup for each subfigure and figure counter

Tags: floats, longtable, counters

This is my `.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{arydshln} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape} % for landspace environment
\usepackage{xltabular} % longtable + tabularx
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}% For colored rows in tables
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz} % text highlighting
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{alphalph} % extended alphabetical 'numbering'
\usepackage{ltcaption}


          
% Long figure
\newenvironment{longfigure}[2][]{%
  % #1 (optional) is arbitrary code to be executed before the longtable
  % #2 is the column specification
  \renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
  \expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}%
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
  \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\LTright}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
  
  #1%
  \begin{longtable}{#2}
}{\end{longtable}} 
            

\begin{document}

% works outside long figure...
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = centering, singlelinecheck = false}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{longfigure}[\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01333333\textwidth}]{@{}cccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig:cc}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises (continued)}
\endhead

% doesnt work inside...
% \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
% \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = centering, singlelinecheck = false}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\

\begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} \\

\end{longfigure}


\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}


\begin{longfigure}[\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01333333\textwidth}]{@{}cccc@{}}
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises \label{fig:cc}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption{Empirical Regularities During Currency Crises (continued)}
\endhead

% \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
% \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification = raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} &
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A subfigure}
\end{subfigure} 

\end{longfigure}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

And this is the otput with the highlights indicating things to be fixed:

[image]

1. I would like to make this caption centered. However putting `\captionsetup` before `\begin{subfigure}` gives an error
2. I would like to fix numbering. First figure has Figure 1, second Figure has number 2 bat third has 5 and fourth has 8... How to fix that?

Comment: It is best to ask a separate question for each issue. This allows people who know to solve only one of them to answer and makes the questions more likely to be found by others having the same issue. It will also allow you to make shorter MWEs for each of your problems.